# Server Raspberry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi3

I use a raspberry as a server my local RPI IP is 172.20.10.13 and my application run on port 3000 when I access to localhost:3000 everything work but when I access to 172.20.10.13:3000 I got an error who say "Connection refused" can someone help me ?

Comment: How did you create the server?

Comment: With the ruby on rails framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start server with this command:

```
rails s --binding=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: The 0.0.0.0 address means listen to requests from anywhere.The default in RoR is 127.0.0.1, which means listen to requests from localhost only.

Comment: So if I run the server with rails s -e productin it will probably work too ?